# Abstract modifier on interface method

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

Today I was copying some methods from an abstract class to an Interface and I realized that the compiler does not underline the abstract keyword. I tried to look up the documentation but found nothing about it.

I also put it into SharpLab but see no difference between the two.

```cs
public interface ITestAbstract
{
    public abstract void MyTest();
}

public interface ITest
{
    public void MyTest();
}
```

My guess is, that it is allowed since, by default interface methods are actually abstract methods, or am I missing something out?

Comment: It's probably allowed and not complaining because, as you said, it literally makes no difference. By the way, you don't need to specify the public keyword in interfaces either :-)

It's worthwhile to say that if you use Rider, it recognises the abstract keyword as redundant

Comment: You should specifiy your language-version. In versions prior to 8 both your methods won't compile.

Comment: Ah you are right public is redundant. I hoped i'm missing out on some fancy feature with abstract tho :P

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain C# 10

Comment: This was added in C#8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#modifiers-in-interfaces *"Similarly, although `abstract` is the default on interface members without bodies, that modifier may be given explicitly."*

Comment: @Menyus The docs simply state: `although abstract is the default on interface members without bodies, that modifier may be given explicitly.`. Its akin to you being explicit with your public modifier. Since C#8, modifier were allowed on interface members, even if those explicit modifers are redundant (e.g `public`, `abstract`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature was added in C# 8 - [Default Interface Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods):

> [Modifiers in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#modifiers-in-interfaces)
>
> The syntax for an interface is relaxed to permit modifiers on its members. The following are permitted: `private`, `protected`, `internal`, `public`, `virtual`, `abstract`, `sealed`, `static`, `extern`, and `partial`.

This means that you are not allowed to modify your methods with `abstract` before this.

One of the purposes is to support [reabstraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#reabstraction). Example from the docs:

```
interface IA
{
    void M() { WriteLine("IA.M"); }
}
interface IB : IA
{
    abstract void IA.M();
}
class C : IB { } // error: class 'C' does not implement 'IA.M'.
```